# How to make a strong click like a mouse

Tags: javascript, html

Please, I have been trying to make an audio play automatically for the past three days now, and I haven't had any success with it.
These were what I tried, but they didn't work in my browser, but they work on CodePen.
How do I make the auto-click more real, like a mouse click?

```
<audio src="https://www.bensound.com/bensound-music/bensound-moose.mp3"></audio>
<button id="button" name="member_signup" onclick="test()">
  <i class="fas fa-volume-up"></i>
</button>
```

```
<script>
const button = document.querySelector("#button");
const icon = document.querySelector("#button > i");
const audio = document.querySelector("audio");

button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (audio.paused) {
    audio.volume = 0.2;
    audio.play();
    icon.classList.remove('fa-volume-up');
    icon.classList.add('fa-volume-mute');
    
  } else {
    audio.pause();
    icon.classList.remove('fa-volume-mute');
    icon.classList.add('fa-volume-up');
  }
  button.classList.add("fade");
});
</script>

<script>
window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById('button').click();
  
var scriptTag = document.createElement("script");
scriptTag.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(scriptTag);
}
</script>
```

Comment: *I have been trying to make an audio play automatically* - it is not possible

Comment: That was the most annoying trope of ~1990s-2000 world wide web. Just don't. There is no strong click or anything like that.

Answer (score 2):

Modern web browsers does not actually play the audio automatically without user interaction to prevent annoying or unexpected sounds when visiting a website